# drawing square icons with Google Image Charts

Tags: javascript, google-maps, charts

I'm using Google Image Charts (yes, I know it's deprecated :-)) to draw circular icons on a Google Map, i.e.:

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=it&chs=48x48&chco=33FF33,000000ff,ffffff01&chl=a&chx=000000,0&chf=bg,s,00000000&ext=.png

Is there a way to draw square icons instead? Unfortunately all references to "cht=it" chart type seems to be disappeared from the Net.

Is there an alternative to Google Image Charts for drawing dynamic icons on a Google Map? I need to control dimensions, color, shape and label.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an alternative to Google Image Charts for drawing dynamic
>   icons on a Google Map? I need to control dimensions, color, shape and
>   label.

Yes there is. What you're looking for is [Drawing on the Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#overlay_types). Here you can use your custom icons, whatever shape they maybe.

Some actual examples for the things you've mentioned:

-[Labels example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-labels)

-[Square shapes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/rectangle-simple)

-[Custom shapes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-symbol-custom)

-[Draw on the Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools)